# Updating Apache Camel JPA object in database triggers deadlock

Tags: oracle, jpa, apache-camel

So I have a Apache Camel route that reads `Data` elements from a JPA endpoint, converts them to `DataConverted` elements and stores them into a different database via a second JPA endpoint. Both endpoints are Oracle databases.

Now I want to set a flag on the original `Data` element that it got copied successfully. What is the best way to achieve that?

I tried it like that: saving the ID in the `context` and then reading it and accessing a dao method in the `.onCompletion().onCompleteOnly()`.

```
    from("jpa://Data")
        .onCompletion().onCompleteOnly().process(ex -> {    
            var id = Long.valueOf(getContext().getGlobalOption("id"));
            myDao().setFlag(id);
        }).end()
        .process(ex -> {
            Data data = ex.getIn().getBody(Data.class);
            DataConverted dataConverted = convertData(data);
            ex.getMessage().setBody(data);

            var globalOptions = getContext().getGlobalOptions();
            globalOptions.put("id", data.getId().toString());
            getContext().setGlobalOptions(globalOptions);
        })
        .to("jpa://DataConverted").end();
```

However, this seems to trigger a deadlock, the dao method is stalling on the commit of the update. The only explanation could be that the `Data` object gets locked by Camel and is still locked in the `.onCompletion().onCompleteOnly()` part of the route, therefore it can't get updated there.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the recipient list EIP where first destination is the `jpa:DataConverted` endpoint and the second destination will be the endpoint to set the flag. This way both get the same message and will be executed sequentially.

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/eips/recipientList-eip.html

```
from("jpa://Data")
   .process(ex -> {
            Data data = ex.getIn().getBody(Data.class);
            DataConverted dataConverted = convertData(data);
            ex.getIn().setBody(data);
     })
   .recipientList(constant("direct:DataConverted","direct:updateFlag"))
 .end();

 from("direct:DataConverted")
  .to("jpa://DataConverted")
 .end();

 from("direct:updateFlag")
  .process(ex -> {    
            var id = ((MessageConverted) ex.getIn().getBody()).getId();
            myDao().setFlag(id);
        })
 .end();
```

Keep in mind, you might want to make the route transactional by adding .transacted()

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/eips/transactional-client.html

Comment: I've tried your approach, however the ```myDao.setFlag()``` call simply stalls whenever it tries to commit the updated entity. Setting the flag directly in the ```process``` and sending back the entity via ```.to("jpa://Data")``` also doesn't do anything, without throwing any error though.